# Return unkown errors when I tried scheduling post with image using Facebook Graph API SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I tried scheduling post include images using Facebook Graph API PHP SDK but return "Unknown Errors".

This problem occurs only when scheduling post include images.
When I tried to scheduling post only text, and normal post include images, I successed.

I guess think there is a problem with how to give images when posting on a schedule.
But I didn't find solutions.

Please let me know if you know some solutions.
Thank you.

code

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => {app_id},
    'app_secret' => {app_secret},
    'default_graph_version' => 'v6.0',
]);

$fbApp = new Facebook\FacebookApp( {app_id}, {app_secret} );

if( !empty($aImage['embeds']) || !empty($aImage)){
    try{
        foreach( $aImage['embeds'] as $img ){
            // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
            // image uri in $img
            $response = $fb->post(
                '/me/photos',
                array (
                        'source' => $fb->fileToUpload( $img ),
                        'published' => false
                ),
                {access_token}
            );               
            $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
            $photoIds[] = ['media_fbid' => $graphNode['id']];
        }

    }catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e){
        echo 'Graph returned an error [img]: ' . $e->getMessage();
        die;
    }catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        die;
    }

}

$aData = [
    'message' => 'success',
];
// temporary var
$scheduling_post = true;
if( $scheduling_post ){
    $aData['scheduled_publish_time'] = time() + (24 * 60 * 60);
    $aData['published'] = false;
}

if( !empty($aImage['embeds']) || !empty($aImage) ){

    foreach ( $photoIds as $key => $photoId ) {
        $attachedMediaId = "attached_media[" . $key . "]";

        $aData = array_merge(
            $aData,
            ["$attachedMediaId" => $photoId]
        );
    }
}

try {
    $response = $fb->post(
        '/me/feed',
        $aData,
        {access_token}
    );

    return true;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // return Unknown errors here
    echo 'Graph returned an error [post]: ' . $e->getMessage();
    die;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    die;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure the `fileToUpload` method is supposed to work for _local files_, not URLs.

Comment: If you want to upload a photo from a URL, you need to use the `url` parameter, and provide the URL directly without applying any further methods on it. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/#upload

Comment: You are right. I should use `url` parameter in this case.
And I added `'temporary' => true` parameter to array of image settings, I successed.

Thanks your answer and sharing document.